# Do all my dependencies (libraries that I am using) for my android studios project have to be using a Gradle version equal to or less than mine?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

So let's say I have an application on android studios using Gradle version 4.1 with Gradle plugin version of 3.0. I have added `implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:8.2.1'` to my build.gradle file. However `com.facebook.android:facebook-login:8.2.1` is using Gradle version 4.4.

So the only way for me to use this library (and that version) is if my project is on Gradle version 4.4 or greater?
Or is there a way for me to use that library (and that version) without changing my Gradle version?
Thanks.

Update: More Info

So specifically I am talking about using the [stripe](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android) API. I was on version 6.1.2 but because of some new EU law, I need to update the version I am using to at least 9.1.1.

I noticed the only time I get this error 'apptransformClasseswithdesugarfordebug' when trying to run my app, is after they update there Gradle to use version 3.4.1 from 3.4.0 (not the Gradle plugin). On version of Stripe 9.0.0, my app is able to run, however, after switching to version 9.1.1, I get that error.

Note, my project is on Gradle version 3.1.4 and when it's on Stripe version of Gradle 3.4.0, my app is able to run.

So to wrap it up, I need to know if I need to be on the same version, although I doubt it because my app works with 9.0.0 of Stripe, which is using a different version of Gradle.

Comment: Do you mean that the facebook dependency is only compatible with Gradle 4.4 or above and why do you have to use a lower version of Gradle anyway? Moreover, all the maintained third party dependencies work with the latest version of Gradle.

Comment: The facebook dependency is only an example to help illustrate my question. I have to use a lower version of Gradle because some of my reflection code gets ruined upon updating Gradle, amongst other things. So I need to stay on my current version of Gradle. Whereas a library I wish to use is on a higher Gradle version than my project.